# How to force reload a page

Tags: javascript, php, header, refresh, reload

I need to redirect a page to another after 10seconds, and to do that, i'm using php header :

> header( "Refresh:10; url=http://myurl.local/test2.php", true, 303);

But the problem is that when page go to be redirect, a browser dialog box ask for a confirmation (this page ask to confirm the close, some data can be lost ....) and finally don't redirect.

My question is : how can I discard automatically this ?

Warmest thanks !

Comment: Are you doing this after submitting a POST request?

Comment: try this html-code: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; URL=http://myurl.local/test2.php">`

Comment: I tried html code but without success - it's not a post request ; page that i'm trying to load is a dynamic shedule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using OnBeforeUnload() javascript function in the page with this header?
Might help if you would remove that call.

More details: https://www.404techsupport.com/2010/03/ask-404ts-whats-up-with-are-you-sure-you-want-to-navigate-away-from-this-page-dialogs/

Answer (score 0):

Second parameter in the `header()` function is `replace` and [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) mentions that:

> The optional replace parameter indicates whether the header should
>   replace a previous similar header, or add a second header of the same
>   type. By default it will replace, but if you pass in FALSE as the
>   second argument you can force multiple headers of the same type.

So change the parameter to `false` may work for you

```
header( "Refresh:10; url=http://myurl.local/test2.php", false, 303);
```

Comment: Thanks for submitting ideas, unfortunately, it doesn't work ... I'm still looking for a fix :(